# Extra bottom and top space in iPhone X in Xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm using XAML for UI design my app is working fine in less then Iphone X device.Only problem in Iphone X it's getting top and bottom Extra space.

If I use below code for Iphone X Safe area enable, it's getting more space in bottom and top.
`On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);`

I got SafeArea layout setting code here [SetUserSafeArea](https://blog.xamarin.com/making-ios-11-even-easier-xamarin-forms/)

Also i'm using SetHasNavigationBar for disable header navigation title.But there is no luck in Iphone X.

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Here is actual Output in Iphone X
[image]

What i 'm missing in code or setting for Iphone X in Xamarin Form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved this issue.

Here is an answer.

1. PCL create an interface to consume in IOS Native App.

   ```
    public interface IDeviceInfo
    {
        bool IsIphoneXDevice();
    }
   ```
2. Implement this Interface in IOS Native App.

   ```
    [assembly: Dependency(typeof(DeviceInfoService))]
    namespace POC.iOS.DependencyServices
    {
        public class DeviceInfoService:IDeviceInfo
        {
            public DeviceInfoService() { }

            public bool IsIphoneXDevice()
            {
                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone)
                {
                    if ((UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale) == 2436)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. Call this method in Xamarin form using dependency Service. And write the logic for the iPhone X layout.

   ```
    public partial class Page : ContentPage
    {
        public Page()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var isDeviceIphone = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceInfo>().IsIphoneXDevice();
            if (isDeviceIphone)
            {
                var safeInsets = On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SafeAreaInsets();
                safeInsets.Bottom =20;
                safeInsets.Top = 20;
                this.Padding = safeInsets;
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: not a generic solution it won't work on all devices we will have issues in iPhone 8 plus for example

Answer (score 2):

The way I got the proper screen size to work on iOS, was by simply adding the proper splash screen images.

For example, in my iOS project I added into my `Resources` folder, an image named `Default-812h@3x.png`, and the dimensions of the image were **1125x2436**.

And then in my `Info.plist` file, I added the following code under the `UILaunchImages` key:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>8.0</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
            <string>Default-812h</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
            <string>Portrait</string>
            <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
            <string>{375, 812}</string>
        </dict>
        ... other launch images ...
    </array>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recently had the same issue.  What I found out was that iOS determines if your app can handle iPhone X by the splash screen.  There were no splash screen images that would work.  I had to create a storyboard and use that for my splash screen.  This link should help you out: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Answer (score 1):

SafeAreaInsets did trick for us.

In AppDelegate.CS,

```
base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
```

should be replaced with below code:

```
var result = base.FinishedLaunching(uiApplication, launchOptions);
            try {
                if (UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow != null) {
                    double top = 0;
                    double bottom = 0;
                    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(11, 0)) {
                        top = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.SafeAreaInsets.Top;
                        bottom = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom;
                    }
//Store safe area values using NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults 
                    DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().AddOrUpdateValue("IPhoneXSafeTop", top);
                    DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().AddOrUpdateValue("IPhoneXSafeBottom", bottom);
                    DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService>().Save();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Ex in FinishedLaunching: " + ex.Message);
            }
            return result;
```

In PCL, xaml.cs file add below code in Constructor:

```
var IPhoneXSafeBottom = DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService> ().GetValueOrDefault<Double> ("IPhoneXSafeBottom", 0);
var IPhoneXSafeTop = DependencyService.Get<ISettingsService> ().GetValueOrDefault<Double> ("IPhoneXSafeTop", 0);
            if (IPhoneXSafeBottom > 0) {
                MainLayout.Padding = new Thickness(0, IPhoneXSafeTop, 0, IPhoneXSafeBottom);

            }
```

Comment: Tried this code there is no changes, and we don't need to add large code to save constant values.

Comment: To persist values even when user kill and open app back, we need this code.. Splash and Background images need to place of size 1125x2436.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I'm not too late. This is what worked for me.

`AppShell.xaml`:

```
<Shell ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true" Padding="0">
...
</Shell>
```