# Popup Not displaying correctly in iPhone X - Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image: Popup Not displaying correctly in iPhone X]

How to get rid of the bottom space in xamarin forms iPhone X

Comment: Possible duplicate (I found when googling the exact text in the desc of this question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49166915/extra-bottom-and-top-space-in-iphone-x-in-xamarin-form

Comment: Not working for a popup page

Comment: @MainakChoudhury Hi , could you share the code of how to popup a page ？

Answer (score 0):

the space that is seen is due to its home button not sure if it will be managed or not but you can try by

just adding this 2 lines to your xaml page/popuppage

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```

and also try setting background color of the page